# How to mark up 1 column (without rows) and 2 columns with 3 rows in each column

Tags: layout

1) 1st column should have the same height as the other 2
2) 1st column should have 40% width, whereas each other columns have 30%
3) rows in the last 2 columns should have the same height
4) First 2 rows should have 40% height, whereas the last row on 20%

I attached a picture to make it clear  [image: layout]
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html, #fs { 
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#i1-table { 
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
} 
#i1-trow { 
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#i1-rowspan { 
display: table-cell;
height:100%;
width:40%;
background-color:red;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
} 
#i1-rowcont { 
display: table-cell;
height:100%;
width:60%;
} 
#i1-table-in { 
display:table;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
.i1-rowcont-row1 { 
display: table-row;
height:40%;
width:100%;
} 
.i1-rowcont-row2 { 
display: table-row;
height:20%;
width:100%;
} 
.i1-cell1 { 
display: table-cell;
width:50%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.i1-cell2 { 
display: table-cell;
width:50%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="fs">
<div id="i1-table">
<div id="i1-trow">
<div id="i1-rowspan">
    1
</div> 
<div id="i1-rowcont">
<div id="i1-table-in">
<div class="i1-rowcont-row1">    
<div class="i1-cell1" style="background-color:blue">
    2
</div>
<div class="i1-cell1" style="background-color:yellow">
    3
</div>
</div>    
<div class="i1-rowcont-row1">    
<div class="i1-cell1" style="background-color:gray">
    4
</div>
<div class="i1-cell1" style="background-color:cyan">
    5
</div>
</div>    
<div class="i1-rowcont-row2">    
<div class="i1-cell2" style="background-color:magenta">
    6
</div>
<div class="i1-cell2" style="background-color:green">
    7
</div>
</div>    
</div>  
</div>    
</div>    
</div>  
</div>
```